# How many arguments does check_box ACTUALLY take?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm experiencing some frustration with the rails 4 check_box.
The Rails 4 Documentation at http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box
is so very, very clear on the subject:
`check_box(object_name, method, options = {}, checked_value = "1", unchecked_value = "0")`
and yet
`<%= f.check_box("dish", "alcohol", {:class => "microallergen alcohol"}, 1, 0 ) %>`
throws
`wrong number of arguments (5 for 1..4)`
Is there an accepted solution/explanation I'm missing?
Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the Rails 4 documenation is correct. It's a little tricky to read, but I believe the object_name (first argument) is actually specified by `f.`

Can you try this:

```
<%= f.check_box("alcohol", {:class => "microallergen alcohol"}, 1, 0 ) %>
```

If you simply used `check_box`, then you would need to specify the object_name as you did in your example.

Comment: thanks for the reply Jay. In the absence of a clear solution at the time, I moved away from check boxes entirely, replacing them with images that toggle a box shadow and write to a hidden text field. I'm going to mark your answer as correct in the hopes that it helps someone else out, though I can't actually implement your solution to know for sure.

Comment: Thanks! I had the exact same problem and found your question at the top of Google results. Hopefully it helps someone else (the above is how I solved it)